# How to append a count number in duplicate values in a column and update in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently my table looks like this; I want to add the count numbers with distinct `InstanceId` and duplicate values.

| Id | InstanceId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 2 | 1 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 3 | 2 | ETLInstance |
| 4 | 3 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 5 | 3 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 6 | 2 | ETLInstance |
| 7 | 2 | ETLInstance |

I want the output to be like this:

| Id | InstanceId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 2 | 1 | DiscoveryInstance_Backup_1 |
| 3 | 2 | ETLInstance |
| 4 | 3 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 5 | 3 | DiscoveryInstance_Backup_1 |
| 6 | 2 | ETLInstance_Backup_1 |
| 7 | 2 | ETLInstance_Backup_2 |

I don't want to update the first value and update should start with the next duplicate value in the column.

How to update this table to make this output possible in SQL Server query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is using the `row_number()` like this
This solution uses your new column `instanceid` to get the correct data

```
select t.id,
       case when rownumber > 1 then t.Name + '_Backup_' + convert(varchar(10), t.rownumber - 1)
            else t.Name
       end     
from   ( select t.id,
                t.name,
                row_number() over (partition by t.Name, t.instanceid order by t.id) as rownumber
         from   mytable t
       ) t
order by t.id
```

See [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06e4a6bff36318e52335afe5a7123814)

output is

| id | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 2 | DiscoveryInstance_Backup_1 |
| 3 | ETLInstance |
| 4 | DiscoveryInstance |
| 5 | DiscoveryInstance_Backup_1 |
| 6 | ETLInstance_Backup_1 |
| 7 | ETLInstance_Backup_2 |

Comment: How to add update statement to update the values in the column 'Name' using this script? @GuidoG

Comment: That depends, do you want the values in the table updated, or just show it like this ?

Comment: I want to show it like this only in the table with the original column names

Comment: If you only want to show it like this, than you don't need any update, just use this query to show the data and that's it

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** This solution addresses the ORIGINAL question and original output. This is no longer valid because you changed your desired output.

You could use rank() and concat in this manner:

```
with cte as (select id, name, rank() over (partition by name order by id) as name_rank
from my_table
)
select t.id, 
case
 when c.name_rank = 1 then t.name
 else concat(t.name, '_Backup_', c.name_rank - 1)
end name
from my_table t
join cte c
  on t.id = c.id
```

Output:

> | id | name |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | DiscoveryInstance |
> | 2 | DiscoveryInstance_Backup_1 |
> | 3 | ETLInstance |
> | 4 | DiscoveryInstance_Backup_2 |
> | 5 | DiscoveryInstance_Backup_3 |
> | 6 | ETLInstance_Backup_1 |

DB-fiddle found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d176fe66383d09e43afc4d6a3bffa46). I see you updated the question after I posted this answer by adding another column, but that does not look important at the moment.

**EDIT**

This is an updated answer (thanks Guido) that would address your newly updated output:

```
with cte as (select id, name, rank() over (partition by name, instanceid order by id) as name_rank
from mytable
)
select t.id, 
case
 when c.name_rank = 1 then t.name
 else concat(t.name, '_Backup_', c.name_rank - 1)
end name
from mytable t
join cte c
  on t.id = c.id
```

Comment: with his new data your result is not correct I think [see this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4a42012acbdb20c85a04ef6bd916c17)

Comment: I edited the question after posting it, so the answer is not valid anymore. @Isolated

Comment: @GuidoG Plus you changed the desired output. Correct, my answer is no longer valid due to the change in the Output.

Comment: I did not changed it, the OP did :) You need only to add the extra column in you partition by and your answer will work again

Comment: See this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c64bea0ce7da04ea7c6246ffd543388) where I altered your solution so it works again, not much change is needed

Comment: @GuidoG That what's i meant, sorry, I meant to address the comment to the OP.